# Talking about system scalability in Japanese

Tags: word-choice, computing, jargon

I work at a big IT company in Japan.
I'm currently working on a scalability project, that is a project to increase the capacity of a web application.

1) How do express "scalability" in Japanese to a non-IT person? If I say "スケーラビリティ" then pretty much no one except computer science people (an English speakers) know what I am talking about.

2) Related to that, how do I say something like "By the end of the year the traffic to our website will increase 500%". like what words should I use for "internet traffic" or "number of visitors" or "number of transactions".

Comment: Can you show us what work you've done to solve this problem? We're not a translation service.

Comment: It's worth noting that, even among English speakers, "scalability" often doesn't mean much except to computer science people.

Comment: what kind of "work" do you want me to show? These terms do not exist in my dictionary. If I Google them I just get katakana words.

Comment: The [Japanese Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A9%E3%83%93%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3) may be useful here.

Comment: I've added the jargon tag in case this does turn out to be a hard word to find a translation for, but I've also voted to close it since my first assumption is that you haven't looked for it very hard. I've [requested a translation for the term](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scalability#Translations) on the English Wiktionary by the way. Also, that site does allow people to ask for translations of random phrases. I'll try to find the link for you ...

Comment: Here is the English Wiktionary translation request page. I've even added your request for you (-: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Translation_requests#How_do_express_.22scalability.22_in_Japanese_to_a_non-IT_person.3F

Comment: @hippietrail what other places should I be looking before I post here? Can you send me some links or resources or something. I posted here because I don't know where else to look.

Comment: @icchanobot: Actually I'm not great at that myself. My Japanese is very poor and the best resources are monolingual or designed for people with very good Japanese, from what I gather. I first use (English) Wiktionary and [WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1C). I often peek at Google Translate too, but that must be taken with a large grain of salt and used just as a first approximation for further searches.

Comment: Other useful E<>J resources are ALC at http://eow.alc.co.jp/ (just add the term to search at the end, in either EN or JA), and Weblio at http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/ (again, just add the term on the end).  I note here that ALC's entries for "internet traffic" appear to be more useful than Weblio's, FWIW.

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed that the site software altered the URLs I posted earlier -- add a / at the end, and *then* add your term to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general purposes, if something is "scalable", we mean it can be expanded or extended usefully.  Expansion or extension in this sense is 拡張 (*kakuchō*) in Japanese.  So to say it's extend*ible*, we would say it is 拡張可能 (*kakuchō kanō*).  The quality of being extendible / scalable would be 拡張可能性 (*kakuchō kanōsei*), or possibly just 拡張性 (*kakuchōsei*).